# Обучение нейрона смещения

Tags: математика, нейронные-сети

Недавно начал изучать машинное обучение и наткнулся на одну [статью](https://habr.com/ru/articles/313216/), но там не описано каким образом обучать нейрон смещения, поэтому я не могу написать нейросеть полноценно. Опишите пожалуйста как мне его обучить и уменьшить потери.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: метод обучения нейрона смещений зависит от типа сети, которую вы строите. Например, есил у вас адаптивный линейный нейрон, то там обучение происходит с использованием градиентного спуска, считается градиент, но значение нейрона смещения задается вычитанием градиента умноженного на скорость обучения. W0_новое значение=W0-(скорость обучения)*Сумма(y(i)-предсказанное значение(i))